# Ember.js removes x-editable from values in table when using sortProperties

Tags: javascript, ember.js, x-editable

I have a table with data that I sort using ember's built in sortProperties in the controller. I also have a filtering mechanism where I filter the data with the following code:

```
  filteredContent: function() {
    var filter = this.get('filter'),
        regex  = new RegExp(filter, 'gi'),
        data   = this.get('arrangedContent');

    return data.filter(function(item) {
      return item.get('name').match(regex) || item.get('email').match(regex) || (item.get('role') && item.get('role').match(regex));
    });
  }.property('sortProperties', 'sortAscending', 'filter', '@each.isNew'),
```

I use a plugin called x-editable (http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) to make each value in the table editable by simply clicking on it. Unfortunately, this doesn't work when using the filtering and ember's sortProperties. When disabling those functions, x-editable works, but filtering and sortProperties seemingly removes the generated x-editable html/logic and replaces it with new html:

It goes from this:

```
<a class="user-email editable editable-click" data-type="text" data-id="email" data-pk="1" data-placement="right" data-placeholder="Required" data-title="Enter user email">dummy_email_214@gmail.com</a>
```

To this:

```
<a class="user-email" data-type="text" data-id="email" data-pk="1" data-placement="right" data-placeholder="Required" data-title="Enter user email"><script id="metamorph-789-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>dummy_email_214@gmail.com<script id="metamorph-789-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script></a>
```

Now, I get that ember needs to replace the content of the `a` in order to create the value binding, but it seemingly replaces the whole `a` and recreates it, but without the x-editable html and logic.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Thanks

Theo

EDIT: Here's the full code for my table:

```
<table id="users-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped searchable-table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="name" width="20%" {{action "sortBy" "name"}}>Name</th>
      <th id="email" width="25%" {{action "sortBy" "email"}}>Email</th>
      <th id="password" width="30%" {{action "sortBy" "password"}}>Password</th>
      <th id="role" width="10%" {{action "sortBy" "role"}}>Role</th>
      <th id="active" width="10%" {{action "sortBy" "active"}}>Active</th>
      <th class="non-sortable" width="5%"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    {{#each user in filteredContent}}
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a class="user-name" data-type="text" data-id="name" data-pk="1" data-placement="right" data-placeholder="Required" data-title="Enter user name">{{user.name}}</a>
        </td>

        <td>
          <a class="user-email" data-type="text" data-id="email" data-pk="1" data-placement="right" data-placeholder="Required" data-title="Enter user email">{{user.email}}</a>
        </td>

        <td>
          <a class="user-password" data-type="text" data-id="password" data-pk="1" data-placement="right" data-placeholder="Required" data-title="Enter user password">{{user.password}}</a>
        </td>

        <td><a class="user-role" data-type="select" data-id="role" data-pk="1" data-title="Select user role">{{user.role}}</a></td>
        <td><a class="user-active" data-type="select" data-id="active" data-pk="1" data-title="Select whether the user is currently active">{{user.active}}</a></td>

        <td style="text-align: center">
          <a {{action 'deleteUser' user }} alt="Delete user" style="cursor: pointer">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

afterRenderEvent:

```
  afterRenderEvent: function() {
    // set default sorting
    this.get('controller').send("sortBy", "name", false);

    // registers the editors, their validators and their respective options

    this.registerEditors();
  },
```

Comment: Can you show the template for a link link element?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean... but I added the code for the entire table in my initial post

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown where you are calling `.editable()`. What is happening is that the javascript to initialize the editors is running before your view is inserted into the DOM.

You need to use `didInsertElement` in your `view` to call `.editable()` after the view is inserted into the DOM.

Implement the following in your view:

```
didInsertElement: function(){
    this.$('#users-table').editable();
}
```

Comment: This is actually what I'm already doing. Or rather, in didInsertElement I'm using Ember.run.scheduleOnce to run afterRenderEvent, which is practically the same. Interestingly though, commenting out the this.get('controller').send("sortBy", "name", false); line in my afterRenderEvent (see OP for full code), x-editable works, until sorting or searching again, which removes x-editable. Changing the order of the calls (sortBy after registerEditors and vice-versa) doesn't have an effect